# Nodes aware of relative position of other nodes in Java

Tags: java, nodes

So I'm working on a small exercise in programming Java, I've created a couple classes that simply draws a black background, and then, from the center, draws circles a radius apart from eachother in 90 degree rotations (code at bottom of post).

Now, just using a "random" seed to determine direction of travel, this always trends downward. Every time. So what I want to do now, is try and show my circles where the other circles are, and give them an inclination to bend their movement towards another circle (without existing ON another circle other than the parent). I can handle that part, but I want an efficient means of communicating location between my "nodes" or "circles". I could build a string array with x,y and read through that list each time I am constructing my seed, but this seems like an inefficient way of doing it. I would much rather find some way where a circle can look around it and find other circles within proximity. Is there any way to do this? I don't mind some reading and homework, I'm mostly looking for a good strategy to start looking at.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FlowerOfLife extends JFrame {
    private Circle Origin = null;



    public FlowerOfLife() {
        // Default layout manager is BorderLayout.  
        // Adding graphic component to center section will expand  
        // it to fill the available space so it does not need to  
        // provide any size hints for this parent container now.  
        GraphicPanel graphicPanel = new GraphicPanel();
        add(graphicPanel);     // default center section  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        setSize(400,400);  
        setLocation(200,200);  
        setVisible(true);   
    }

    /** 
     * Container method draws container and passes graphics context 
     * on to components for them to draw themselves. You can draw 
     * over everything in the content pane with this method... 
     */  
    public void paint(Graphics gr)  
    {  
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        // see what happens when you remove/move this next line  
        super.paint(g);  

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,  
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);  
        int w = getWidth();  
        int h = getHeight();
        g.setPaint(Color.white);//First there is one...
        Origin = new Circle(g, w/2, h/2, ((w+h)/2)/35);
        g.setPaint(Color.white.darker());

        Circle[] circleArray = new Circle[100];
        for(int i=0;i<circleArray.length;i++){
            circleArray[i] = new Circle(g,i>0?circleArray[i-1]:Origin);
        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        new FlowerOfLife();  
    } 

}

class Circle{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int r;
    private Circle next;
    private Circle last;
    private int    seed;

    public Circle(Graphics2D g, Circle c){ 
        c.next = this;
        this.last = c;
        this.r  = c.r; //Copy radius
        //We set these now, and modify the necessary ones.
        this.x = c.x;
        this.y = c.y;
        this.r = c.r;

        //Move the new circle into position based on seed.
        this.seed = (int) (Math.random()*4);
        if(this.seed==0){//Stay here, and grow a little...
//          this.r+=1;
        }else if(this.seed==1){//Move left, by r.
            this.x-=c.r;    
        }else if(this.seed==2){//Move up,   by r.
            this.y+=c.r;
        }else if(this.seed==3){//Move right,by r.
            this.x+=c.r;
        }else{//(this.seed==4) //Move down, by r.
            this.y-=c.r;
        }
        sleep((int)(Math.random())*9000+100);//Random(ish) life.
        //Draw the new circle
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,r*2,r*2));


    }
    public Circle(Graphics2D g,int x, int y, int r){
        /**
         *  The ellipse draws from the designated point, down and right.
         * The below permits the center to be declared in a more natural
         * way. Used for the first declaration.
        **/
        this.last = null; //Parent.
        this.x = x-r;
        this.y = y-r;
        this.r = r;
        this.seed = 0;
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,r*2,r*2));
    }
    private void sleep(int ms){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class GraphicPanel extends JPanel  
{  
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
    {  
        super.paintComponent(g);  
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;  
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,  
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()));
    }  
}
```

Comment: Its sounds sort of like a graph, where you have nodes that know about their connected nodes.  If you expand on Jim Barrows' answer, you could implement a CircleNode, which has a position in the board and a List/Set of neighbors, and a Board which contains all nodes.  Then, starting from any node, you would know who your neighbors where.  If you are moving a piece around, it could interrigate the current node, get the neighbors, and upon choosing to move to a neighbor, interrigate it for the pieces new possition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circles can exist on a "board", which would be a two-dimensional array.  You could then give each circle a view of the board.  You could also have the board determine where to put the next circle.

Comment: I'd like to leave the circles defining eachother, I like the idea of using this naturally downward trend as a "gravity" of sorts to draw circles away from eachother while they still simultaneously try to hold onto eachother. I think I have a good idea of how to make this board you describe - I will work on it throughout the afternoon and see if I can't get a functional one. I will post back later, thanks!